# Get file name and path without opening file

Tags: vb.net, file, path, directory

I am studying Visual Basic .NET.

And, I am trying to find way to get file name and directory path.

For example, When I click button , then we can search file by openfile dialog.

When We select the file then we will get path and file name such as  "C:\data\picture\my_pic.jpg".

However, program does not open file. It just return the string type path for file.

I am not really sure how to get path.

Does anyone know how to get path ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with the file? Do you just want to get the path to it, or are you trying to do something else (open, edit, delete, move, etc.)?

Comment: I need to get the filename and path to display.

Comment: I think ,  One of the answers solved my problems :). Anyway , thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is the path, and I'm assuming you're using Winforms, then :

```
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        MsgBox(ofd.FileName)
    End If
End Using
```

An `OpenFileDialog` doesn't actually open the file - it returns the path (or paths) to the selected files via the `.FileName` (or `.FileNames` for multiple files) property, and your application then can use them in whatever way it wants - either opening the file or doing something else to it, etc.

Comment: thanks Its working. I don't why I kept thinking that OpenFileDialog is opening file. :D. THANKS!!

Comment: @BobMa Yes, it perhaps should be named `SelectFileDialog` rather than `OpenFileDialog` - I hadn't considered it before, but it is a bit inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default 'do this when file is selected' event within the OpenFileDialog. All it does is allows a user to select a file, and then you determine what to do with it.

The OpenFileDialog class has an event called `FileOK`, which gets fired after a user selects a file and clicks the 'OK' button. If you create a sub that `Handles OpenFileDialog.FileOK`, you can then access the `OpenFileDialog.FileName`.

The `FileName` will return the full path to the file. Once you have this, it is up to you to determine what to do with the file. If you want to display the image in your program, perhaps create a `PictureBox` and load the image in it. If you want to load it in an external program, use `Process.Start()` and pass the file path as a parameter to it.